# Category RSS feed doesn't show category name

Tags: categories, rss

I'm pulling an RSS feed from a custom post type "blogs" under a category of "workers-compensation". Here is the URL: http://www.company.com/category/workers-compensation/feed/?post_type=blog

The feed works fine, but I'm unable to pull the category name so that feed readers can display the title similar to this "Company >> Worker's Compensation", but I'm stuck with "Company >> " (where nothing gets pulled in for the second part).

I'll admit I'm a pretty big RSS nub, so any and all help here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!